# Technology and logics behind BTC flashing apps

Tags: fraud

How they develop BTC flashing software ? I mean, is there any technical way to send fake BTC ? If not, how BTC flashing app works.. I am just curious ..

Comment: What is 'BTC flashing software'?

Comment: I also dont know much.. There are many apps in google claim to send fake BTC to any BTC enabled wallet (eg blockchain.info wallet). the fake BTC will stay there for few hours and will eventually flushed out by the receiving wallet..

Comment: That sounds nonsensical, I would suspect that many of these apps are just malware designed to steal your bitcoin, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical way to send fake BTC

I surmise the way BTC flasher apps work is not by sending fake BTC but by

- tricking the app purchaser out of their money.
- tricking the app purchaser into installing malware.
- opening the app purchaser to extortion.